# How to get the number of graphs in a NetworkX graph set?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a set of graphs stored as a NetworkX class. Is there any command to get the number of graphs in the NetworkX graph set? Something like .shape in pandas dataframe. Currently, I use the following code, but I am looking for a simpler way.

```
x = 0
for ii, bb in enumerate(graph_set):
    x += 1
print(x)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what a graph set is?  I'm not familiar with this networkx class.

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean by graph_set? There is no such class in networkx. https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/index.html

Comment: Consider I have graph_set and inside graph_set I have graph1, graph2, ..., graphn. Acutally, I am not sure what we call it, maybe it is not a class.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `len()` like this:

```
len(graph_set)
```